# Terraform Values from .tfvars are not loading when using Multi Level Maps

Tags: terraform

I am getting below errors on "terraform plan" when trying to use a multi-level map with `.tfvar`. I request you to help me correct my `.tfvars`

**.tfvars**

```
instance_config = {
  default = {
    test-vm1 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm1"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
        instance_type =  "n1-standard-4"
       },

    test-vm2 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm2"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        instance_type =  "f1-micro"
       },

    test-vm3 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm2"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        instance_type =  "f1-micro"
       }
  }
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "instance_config" {

  type = map(object({
        instance_name  = string
        instance_image = string
        instance_type  = string
       }))
  
  default = {
    test-vm1 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm1"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
        instance_type =  "n1-standard-4"
       },

    test-vm2 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm2"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        instance_type =  "f1-micro"
       }
  }
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {

  for_each     = var.instance_config

  name         = each.value.instance_name
  machine_type = each.value.instance_type
  tags         = var.instance_tags

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = each.value.instance_image
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = var.gcp_network
  }
}
```

when I do terraform plan, I see this issue
`terraform plan -var-file=profiles/liverpool.tfvars`

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│
│   on profiles/liverpool.tfvars line 11:
│   11: instance_config = {
│   12:   default = {
│   13:     test-vm1 = {
│   14:         instance_name  = "test-vm1"
│   15:         instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
│   16:         instance_type =  "n1-standard-4"
│   17:        },
│   18:     test-vm2 = {
│   19:         instance_name  = "test-vm2"
│   20:         instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
│   21:         instance_type =  "f1-micro"
│   22:        },
│   23:     test-vm3 = {
│   24:         instance_name  = "test-vm2"
│   25:         instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
│   26:         instance_type =  "f1-micro"
│   27:        }
│   28:   }
│   29: }
The given value is not valid for variable "instance_config": list of map of string required.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `default` in your `.tfvars`. Thus it should be:

```
instance_config = {

    test-vm1 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm1"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
        instance_type =  "n1-standard-4"
       },

    test-vm2 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm2"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        instance_type =  "f1-micro"
       },

    test-vm3 = {
        instance_name  = "test-vm2"
        instance_image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        instance_type =  "f1-micro"
       }

}
```

Comment: I tried, but I am still getting the same error `The given value is not valid for variable "instance_config": list of map of string required.`

Comment: @Eva You must have some old definition somewhere, that is seeks for a list. Please make the question in SO, as terraform should not be on SF.

Comment: Sure I will post in SO. really appreciate your help